# Having Authentication Error While Trying To Access Mysql Database From Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, authentication, visual-studio-2012

I am pretty new at Mysql and I am basically trying to connect the Mysql Database at my computer (using localhost) from Windows Form by clicking a button but I am getting Authentication errors no matter what I do.
This is the first error I got(KinderGray is my Computer Name):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToKl4.png

After I created new user and granted all privileges, I started to get similar but different error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T868k.png

I know it is for security purposes and giving all privileges to a user is not so good idea. The thing I want to do is connect the database, but also avoiding security vulnerabilities is as important. Any idea would be useful for me, so what would you suggest? Thanks...

This is my Connection code by the way.

```
class Connection {
        private MySqlConnection connect;
        private string Server;
        private string Database;
        private string Userid;
        private string Pass;
        public Connection() { Baglan(); }
        public void Baglan(){
            Server = "localhost";
            Database = "market";
            Userid = "root";
            Pass = "";
            string ConnectionString = "SERVER=" + Server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + Database + ";" + "UID" + Userid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + Pass + ";";
            connect = new MySqlConnection();
        }
        public bool BaglantiAc() {
            try { connect.Open();
            return true;
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Hata Kodu: " + ex);
                return false;
            }

        }
        public bool BaglantiKapa()
        {
            try
            {
                connect.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connection d1 = new Connection();
        d1.Baglan();
        if (d1.BaglantiAc()) label3.Text = "Bağlantı başarılı.";
        else label3.Text = "Bağlantı başarısız.";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: Do you not have a password, or have you redacted it? Please look at this tutorial: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I don't think it is about password, I changed the password of root but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you setting the connection string of the MySqlConnection object anywhere? You need something like `connect.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;`